# should we always place our own packages in vendor/ folder when developing a golang library?

Tags: go, vendor, glide-golang

recently i read a article http://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vendor/, there are some recommendations, one of them is :

> Libraries (codebases without a `main` package) should not store outside packages in a `vendor/` folder in their VCS unless they have a specific reason and understand why they're doing it.

my question is :

according to this recommendation, should we always place our own packages(not those third party packages) in `vendor/` folder when developing a golang library ?

Answer (score 1):

"outside packages" means packages that live outside this repo. So, if the packages are in separate repos from the code that imports them: Yes, vendor them.

If you just want to write and use multiple packages while implementing your library: No, put them in subfolders outside vendor/ in the library repo

For example

`...
▸ server/
    server.go "package server"
▸ store/
▸ testutils/
▾ vendor/
  ▸ bitbucket.org/
  ▸ github.com/
...`

Comment: although your reply is not the direct answer of my question, you clarify what `outside pakcages` which confuse me means. thanks! https://github.com/mattfarina/golang-broken-vendor makes me understand why a library should not place third-party packages into `vendor/` directory.

Comment: how does vendor package manager such as `glide` manage third-party packages when we put them into library's codebase directory structure while developing a library?

Comment: @BruceAuyeung I have only used `godep`, with which: You run `go get foo/package1 bar/package2...` to install packages into your gopath, then run `godep restore && godep save ./...` to copy the packages from gopath to `<project>/vendor/`. I expect that with glide, you similarly do not have to put anything in the vendor folder manually.

Comment: but the recommendation said do not put 3rd party libs into vendor, right ?

Comment: I only have experience with programs that have a main.go so I don't know why that recommendation was made. If your code needs the dependency, and you don't vendor that dependency, I expect users must manually `go get dependency/...`

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes no sense to add your own packages inside a vendor/ directory, because the vendor directory is meant for code external to your project.

What this recommendation means is: If you are developing a library, do not use vendor/ to store third-party libraries unless you know what you're doing and why you're doing it.